# Explanation on a theorem of linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, symmetric-matrices

> "Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with a orthonormal basis of $n$ eigenvectors, show that $A$ is symmetric."

No idea how to prove this.

Comment: Do you mean orthonormal basis of $n$ _eigenvectors_? And also, you say you don't have any idea, but [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). I think you know a lot of things about orthonormal basis vectors and about symmetric matrices. You might not know exactly how a finished, polished proof should look, but that's an entirely different thing.

Comment: yes eigenvectors and no i actually don't even know how to start this proof

Comment: Not knowing how to start a proof and not knowing how to start _looking for_ a proof are two entirely different things. What do you know about symmetric matrices and their eigenvectors? What do you know about orthonormal bases? That's where you start looking for a proof. And we can't really help you until you give us a good indication of how much you know about these things. So, what do you know? Fill up your question post with things you know that seem relevant, see how many dots you can connect on your own.

Comment: @Arthur i know the definition of symmetric matrices, and the definition of orthogonal matrices, also i know about eigenvalues and vectors and how to find them using determinants but that's about it

Comment: The matrix is going to be of the form $B^{-1}DB$ where $B$ is orthonormal and $D$ is diagonal, now transpose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more beautiful ways to prove this. However, here is a way that works.

Let $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ denote the orthonormal eigenvektors. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be their eigenvalues. <strike>Since these eigenvektors are orthonormal, the eigenvalues are not zero.</strike>

Since $b_i^tb_j=\delta_{ij}$ by definition the matrix $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ has a natural inverse: $B^{-1}=B^t$.

Let $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ we have: $AB=\Lambda B$. And $(B^t\Lambda B)_{ij}=b_i^t\lambda_jb_j=\lambda_j\delta_{ij}=\Lambda_{ij}$. Thus $B^tAB=\Lambda$ and $A=B\Lambda B^t$.

$$\Rightarrow A^t=(B\Lambda B^t)^t=B\Lambda^t B^t=B\Lambda B^t=A.$$

Comment: It is possible for the eigenvalues to be zero; I'm not sure why you are claiming they are nonzero. This doesn't affect the rest of your proof though.

Comment: True and I don't even need that.

Comment: @Snake707 thanks for the feedback, just one thing (sorry if that's too stupid for me to ask) what "btibj=δij" on line 2 of your proof means?

Comment: It means that the scalar product of $b_i$ and $b_j$ is the same as the Kronecker delta. $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. So $\delta_{ij}$ is another way of denoting the identity matrix.